# How to Rename a Table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm writing a SQL script to rename many tables in a MySQL database. I would like to change the prefix to a new value. The code that I'm using is shown below. It is possible to use variables in a "rename table" command?

Thanks.

```
set @oldTable = 'j5xqy_banner_clients';
set @newTable = 'p5gsk_banner_clients';

rename table @oldTable to @newTable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, but you'll need to use a prepared statement:

```
SET @oldTable = 'a_b';
SET @newtable = 'b_b';
SET @sql = CONCAT('RENAME TABLE ', @oldTable, ' TO ', @newtable);

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0386f/1)

Answer (score 1):

Good way of remembering the rule for this:

Variables and parameters can be used in SQL only where you would otherwise use a single **constant value**, not where you would use an identifier (column name, table name, etc.), or an SQL keyword, or an expression.

Any dynamic content you want in the SQL syntax must be there *before* it is parsed. That's why it works if you make a string, and then prepare/execute it, as shown in the answer from @sgeddes.